# Partitioning the columns of a matrix

Tags: integers, partitions, matrix

I thought about this problem for a while now and am not able to find a solution for it, be it a direct algorithm or a reduction to a known problem, so I'm asking here:

Suppose you have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{N}^{n\times m}$ with integer entries. I want to partition the columns of $A$ into $k$ groups (or $k$ matrices), such that the sum of the minima of every row in each group is minimized. To illustrate: Suppose
$$
A = \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
   3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
   6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2\\
\end{array}
\right]\text{ .}
$$

If I partition the columns into the following three matrices
$$
A_1 = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
   \color{red}1 & 2 \\
   \color{red}3 & 4 \\
   6 & \color{red}5 \\
\end{array}
\right],\qquad
A_2 = \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \color{red}3 & 5\\
   \color{red}5 & 7\\
   4 & \color{red}2\\
\end{array}
\right],\qquad
A_3 = \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   \color{red}4\\
   \color{red}6\\
   \color{red}3\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$

the "score" would be $(1+3+5)+(3+5+2)+(4+6+3)=32$, the sum of all the red entries (which are the minimal entries in each row).

Also, there is a given minimum size $M$ for the groups, so each group must have at least $M$ columns.

Is there any feasible algorithm for minimizing this?

Comment: Just to be clear, in this example $k=3$? Is there a requirement that each group is nonempty?

Comment: @Albert Hendriks yes, the example is k=3. There may be restrictions on the size of the groups, I forgot to add. I updated my question accordingly